# why my query is not working for mysql? The syntax seems to be right

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute a register class.But the query does not work(the query is highlighted. It seems to be a simple problem but i don't see it.  I echo the query and copy and execute it via phpmyadmin sql query box, it says error 1064. I can't seem to find any problem with it.

```
    <?php
class register
{
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
    protected $email;
    protected $postcode;

    public function __construct()
    {   
    }

    public function insertuser($username, $password,$email, $postcode)
    {
        $this->_email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
        $this->_password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
        $this->_username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $this->_postcode = mysql_real_escape_string($postcode);



    **$query = "INSERT INTO 'users'('user_id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'postcode') VALUES  (NULL,'{$username}','{$password}','{$email}','{$postcode}');";**


        echo $query;
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        return $result;
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: You are using quotes incorrectly. Also you should not be using regular mysql, instead research mysqli or PDO.

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

[`error 1064`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_parse_error) means SQL syntax error. You used single quotes around the table name and the column names: `'` . Replace them by backtics: `

```
"INSERT INTO `users` (
  `user_id`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `postcode`
) VALUES  (
   NULL,'{$username}','{$password}','{$email}','{$postcode}'
);"
```

Further note, that you should not write new code using the mysql extension. It has been marked deprecated by the PHP developers. Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems to be wrong.  Table and column names should not have quotes around them.  They should have backticks or nothing.  Otherwise they are treated as string literals.

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, username, password, email, postcode)
VALUES  (NULL,'{$username}','{$password}','{$email}','{$postcode}')
```

You also don't need the field list if the values list is complete and in order.  The ending semicolon is undesirable (though ineffective).

---

Your code is vulnerable to injection.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli

Answer (score 0):

You have single quotes around your table and columns. You are confusing these with backticks - which are unnecessary unless you have used a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html) (which you should avoid IMO).

Also, you were not using your sanitized variables and therefore vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, username, password, email, postcode) VALUES (NULL,'{$this->_username}','{$this->_password}','{$this->_email}','{$this->_postcode}');
```

*Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Single quotes around column names are always wrong. If you want to enclose column names, you should use backticks.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely consider switching to mysqli in addition to using prepared statements. Using prepared statements will make your queries easier and further protect you from injections.

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

As for your errors, there are a few things wrong. Do not call the DB using quotes. Do not treat table names with quotes. Those are all things pointed out by Explosion Pills.

Finally, I don't see where you opened a mysqli connection.